# How to post->post_content as Html

Tags: wordpress, post

I have to post a content as html in bellow code you can see that div `<div class='pbg_info'` i want post as html using `$post->post_content="` and any other way

The div class 'pbg_info' is script of pay by group payment gateway to display the pay group button.

If anybody have any idea how achieve this then let me know.

```
$post->post_content="
    <div class='pbg_info'
    data-purchase-image-url='http://example.com/picture.png'
    data-purchase-name='Awesome Escape'
    data-purchase-inventory-id='ESCAPE-23'
    data-purchase-cost='"<?php echo $price;" ?>'
    data-purchase-currency='CAD'
    data-purchase-link-url='http://example.com/property'
    data-purchase-description='Great rental for 3 people with lake view.' >
    </div>
    <script src='https://cdn.paybygroup.com/snippet/v2/loader.js?merchant_id=example'>
    </script>";
```

with this code i am getting a output like this. i am expecting a button to display here using this code.

```
data-purchase-image-url=’http://example.com/picture.png’
data-purchase-name=’Awesome Escape’
data-purchase-inventory-id=’ESCAPE-23′
data-purchase-cost=’100′
data-purchase-currency=’CAD’
data-purchase-link-url=’http://example.com/property’
data-purchase-description=’Great rental for 3 people with lake view.’ >
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you have to filter that content before outputting, that means you have to use the code like below :

```
<?php
$content=$post->post_content;
echo apply_filters('the_content', $content);
?>
```